# Monaco: saving preferences to localStorage

Tags: monaco-editor

In the editor you can resize the completions dropdown with a drag handle - this is important to me because the completion items can have wildly different widths.

The new width persists for the duration of that editor, but if you reload the page it's reset to the default.

I can implement this interface as suggested on https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2241#issuecomment-764694521. However I would like to just rely on the default implementation but simply persist all settings to `localStorage`. It seems like that would be such a common case that there would be a simpler way of doing this without reimplementing [storage.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/platform/storage/common/storage.ts).

Is there a way of delegating to the default impl, or adding a listener for changes without overriding the default impl?

Answer (score -1):

See an example of implementing monaco-editor with localstorage on [**Anglo**](https://github.com/sekedus/anglo)

Check settings button (top right): https://sekedus.github.io/anglo/

or, you can test this basic example:

```
<style type="text/css">
#editor{width:100%;height:100vh;}
</style>

<div id="editor"></div>

<script>var require = { paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.32.0/min/vs' } };</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.32.0/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.32.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.32.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function() {
  var editor_html = document.querySelector('#editor');

  var settings = {
    language: 'plaintext',
    theme: 'vs-dark',
    tabSize: 2,
    fontSize: 13,
    wordWrap: 'on',
    contextmenu: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    automaticLayout: true,
    minimap: { enabled: false }
  };

  var local_settings = localStorage.getItem('settings');
  if (local_settings) settings = JSON.parse(local_settings);
  
  var editor_code = monaco.editor.create(editor_html, settings);

  localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settings));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Asalan, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Yunnosch Edited: basic example